# Can we ask questions about who are lawyers who offer service X in a region Y?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm thinking on whether Law.SE might serve a place for the Canadian co-operative movement to store resources on legally incorporating and maintaining co-operatives. I'm wondering whether I could ask and answer my own questions related to specific persons, like "Which lawyers are known for supporting co-operatives in Ontario, Canada?"

Would this be on-topic? If not, what variations of the question might make it go off-topic?

It's very hard to find this information outside word-of-mouth. (I'd generally like to start posting more about co-operative law in Law.SE)

Answer (score 5):

> Would this be on-topic?

It seems off-topic. That form of lawyer referral resource can quickly degenerate in lawyers' cost-free advertising/spam. That is because any lawyer with too much downtime can post a question pretending to be some client in search for *that* lawyer's specialty.

Some on-topic alternatives are "*where do I find court dockets and/or opinions in jurisdiction X?*" (since dockets and opinions list the parties' lawyers) or "*I am experiencing this issue. To what specialty[-ies] of law does this issue pertain?*".

> I'd generally like to start posting more about co-operative law in Law.SE

That would definitely be on topic, and it could highly contribute to co-operatives' understanding of the applicable legal framework.